# md-select multiple is displaying selected options one below the other

Tags: angularjs-material

I am using angularjs material 1.1.0. In the md-select with multiple=true, the selected options are being displayed one below the other like:

[image: Multiple Select in AngularJS Material]

When I look at the HTML created, somehow an extra div is being added to the multiple select html as show below:

```html
<md-select-value class="md-select-value" id="select_value_label_127"><span><div class="md-container"><div class="md-icon"></div></div><div class="md-text ng-binding">Standtag</div>, <div class="md-container"><div class="md-icon"></div></div><div class="md-text ng-binding">Umsatzsteuer</div>, <div class="md-container"><div class="md-icon"></div></div><div class="md-text ng-binding">Verkaufspreis effektiv ohne Umsatzsteuer</div></span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value>
```

```html
<div class="md-container"><div class="md-icon"></div></div>
```

The above div is getting added and that is what causes the selected items to be displayed in rows rather than as single row with comma separated. When I remove the abve div, the selected options are displayed in right format. That div is not there when I check on angularjs website. I am not able to figure out why this extra div is getting added.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to workaround this with a few options:

- Set up CSS rules aimed directly at those divs and set them to `display: inline`
- Try to set the `display: flex` CSS rule for the parent of those divs, hoping that with this they will automatically inline themselves, without line breaks ([see here for more info on this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

Since those divs are automatically created, it might seem hard to apply custom CSS rules to them, since you can't for example add your own CSS classes to those divs directly.

However, you can probably find those divs using combinations of complex CSS selectors, such as `:nth-child`, `[text=]`, `>`, `+`, etc.

For example, let's say the container of those divs has a class `.thisIsMe`, then you could do:

```css
.thisIsMe div {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

---

If none of the above work, you could try to work around it with javascript, with some code to delete those divs automatically for you whenever they appear.

- Perhaps at the `on-change` event. You might have to surround your removals of the divs in `$scope.$evalAsync` or maybe `$timeout` since angularjs often does not apply interface rendering updates synchronously.
- This might not work though, perhaps the divs might reappear after being manually removed like this... The CSS ideas are better, I think.